# How to Construct a Graph?

Tags: java, graph, breadth-first-search, treenode

I'm working on a project that involves parsing through a data file and reading it into a graph. In this graph I must find the shortest distance between two vertices. I've been trying for a couple days actually but I just can't seem to figure out how to even get this graph up.

I tried to use Dijkstra's algorithm but I figured that a simple BFS would be simpler and easier to understand but I do not know how to construct the graph in the first place.

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;

 /* 
  * Here we create an undirected graph
 */
public class Graph 
{

    public int [][] adjmatrix; 
    public int vertices;


    public Graph(int vertices) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        adjmatrix = new int[vertices][vertices];            
        this.vertices = vertices;                           


    }

    public void addEdge(String actor, String actor2, String movie)
    {
        if(getVertex(actor) == -1)
        {

        }
    }


    public int[] neighbors(int vertex) 
    {

        ArrayList<Integer> neighbors = new ArrayList<>(); 

        for (int i = 0; i < vertices; i++) {

            if(adjmatrix[vertex][i] == 0)
            {
                neighbors.add(i);
            }
        }

        int size = neighbors.size();

        int[] neighbor = new int[size];

        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){

            neighbor[i] = neighbors.get(i);
        }
        return neighbor;
    }

    public void makePath(String actor, String actor2)
    {

    }
}
```

The result is to create a graph and make a function that finds the shortest distance. I do not need help figuring out how to find the shortest distance as that function is straightforward for me but I need help constructing the graph in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the number of vertices (only a count of how many there are), use a 2D - Array.

`int [][] edges = new int[vertices][vertices]; // vertices of map`

`edges[BeginningVertex][EndingVertex] = Weight or time needed to cross;`

Comment: Thank you for your input!! I actually have these lines of code in my code however I'm unable to figure out how to fill out the helper functions such as addedge and neighbors. it's sort of hard to explain without a context so I could email you a  picture of what I'm trying to do that would be easier for you to understand.

Comment: To add an edge, do edges[BeginningVertex][EndingVertex] = Weight or time needed to cross; For example, if there was a path in between vertex 1 and 2, weighing 10, you can do, in your addEdge() function, `edges[1][2] = 10`. Note that you actually should do `edges[2][1] = 10` as well.

Comment: I do understand that works for creating basic graphs but the trick here is that I'm creating a graph based on the 6 degrees of Kevin Bacon where I import data of over 2000 movies into this graph so I'm confused as to how neighbors function works and if the makeEdge function stays the same as basic graph implementation

Comment: " I could email you a picture of what I'm trying to do that would be easier for you to understand" please add any essential information to the post itself. A simplified graphic representation could help. I am guessing that every actor is a node (vertice) in the graph and an edge is actually a movie.

Comment: @c0der I actually have finished everything but my BFS algorithm takes way too long to execute, I was hoping you could help optimize it and for that you'd need the rest of my files and materials used :) that's why I'd rather email

Comment: As this Q&A forum is about accumulating knowledge, the posts (including the code) needs to be available to anyone. It is not meant for private Q&A. You are not expected to post the entire code, but an [mcve].  For optimization of code you better use [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that for creating Graph (Directed Graph) and run BFS algorithm ,use this code:

**Graph.java**:

```
public class Graph {

    private final boolean [][]MAT;

    private final int NODE_NUMBER;

    public Graph(int NODE_NUMBER) {
        this.NODE_NUMBER = NODE_NUMBER;
        this.MAT = new boolean [NODE_NUMBER][NODE_NUMBER];
    }



    public void addEdge(int nodeA , int nodeB){
        this.MAT[nodeA][nodeB] = true;
    }


    public boolean hasEdge(int nodeA, int nodeB){
        return MAT[nodeA][nodeB];
    }


    public final int getNodeSize(){
        return NODE_NUMBER;
    }
}
```

**BfsResult.Java**:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class BfsResult {

    private final int root;

    private final boolean []visited;

    private final int []distance;

    private final int []parent;


    public BfsResult(int root, boolean[] visited, int[] distance, int[] parent) {
        this.root = root;
        this.visited = visited;
        this.distance = distance;
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public int getRoot() {
        return root;
    }

    public int getParent(int node){
        return parent[node];
    }

    public int getDistance(int node){
        return distance[node];
    }

    public boolean isAccessible(int node){
        return visited[node];
    }


    public int[] getPath(int node){

        List<Integer> path = new ArrayList <>(  );

        int cur = node;
        do{
            path.add( cur );
            cur = parent[cur];

        }while ( cur != -1 );


        int []pathArray = new int[path.size()];

        for(int i = 0 ; i < path.size() ; ++i){
            pathArray[i] = path.get( path.size() - (i + 1) );
        }

        return pathArray;

    }

    public String getPathString(int node) {
        int[] path = getPath( node );

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(  );

        for ( int i = 0; i < path.length; i++ ) {
            builder.append( path[i] );

            if(i + 1 < path.length){
                builder.append( " -> " );
            }
        }

        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

**BfsAlgorithm.java**:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;


public class BfsAlgorithm {


    private final Graph graph ;
    private final int root;

    public BfsAlgorithm(Graph graph, int root) {
        this.graph = graph;
        this.root = root;
    }

    public BfsResult run() {

        boolean []visit     = new boolean[graph.getNodeSize()];
        int     []distances = new int    [graph.getNodeSize()];
        int     []parents   = new int    [graph.getNodeSize()];

        Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<>();

        visit[root]     = true;
        distances[root] = 0;
        parents[root]   = -1;

        queue.add( root );

        while( !queue.isEmpty() ){

            int currentNode = queue.poll();

            for(int i = 0 ; i < graph.getNodeSize() ; ++i){

                if( graph.hasEdge( currentNode , i ) && !visit[i] ){

                    visit    [i] = true;
                    distances[i] = distances[currentNode] + 1;
                    parents  [i] = currentNode;

                    queue.add(i);
                }
            }
        }

        return new BfsResult( root, visit, distances, parents );


    }
}
```

**Main.java**:

```
public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        //create sample graph with 6 node
        Graph graph = new Graph( 6 );

        //directed edges:
        graph.addEdge( 0 , 1 ); 
        graph.addEdge( 0 , 2 );
        graph.addEdge( 1 , 3 );
        graph.addEdge( 2 , 4 );
        graph.addEdge( 4 , 5 );

        //select root node of bfs
        int root = 0;

        BfsAlgorithm algorithm = new BfsAlgorithm( graph, root );

        BfsResult result = algorithm.run();

        //show result
        for ( int i = 0; i < graph.getNodeSize(); i++ ) {

            if(result.isAccessible( i )){
                System.out.printf("From node %d to %d  is accessible\n" ,result.getRoot() ,i  );
                System.out.printf("Distance between node  %d -> %d  is %d\n" ,result.getRoot() , i , result.getDistance( i ) );
                System.out.printf("Path     between node  %d -> %d  is:\t%s\n" ,result.getRoot() , i , result.getPathString( i ) );
            }else{
                System.out.printf("From node %d to %d  is not accessible!\n" ,result.getRoot() ,i );
            }

            System.out.println("\n ------------------------ \n");
        }



    }


}
```

I run this algorithm for the graph  by root 0:

[image]

result is :

```
From node 0 to 0  is accessible
Distance between node  0 -> 0  is 0
Path     between node  0 -> 0  is:  0

 ------------------------ 

From node 0 to 1  is accessible
Distance between node  0 -> 1  is 1
Path     between node  0 -> 1  is:  0 -> 1

 ------------------------ 

From node 0 to 2  is accessible
Distance between node  0 -> 2  is 1
Path     between node  0 -> 2  is:  0 -> 2

 ------------------------ 

From node 0 to 3  is accessible
Distance between node  0 -> 3  is 2
Path     between node  0 -> 3  is:  0 -> 1 -> 3

 ------------------------ 

From node 0 to 4  is accessible
Distance between node  0 -> 4  is 2
Path     between node  0 -> 4  is:  0 -> 2 -> 4

 ------------------------ 

From node 0 to 5  is accessible
Distance between node  0 -> 5  is 3
Path     between node  0 -> 5  is:  0 -> 2 -> 4 -> 5

 ------------------------
```